# Why does excel round before given precision?

Tags: excel

Why does excel round column C after 15 decimal places and column D after 1 decimal place? Look at the third table, so you can see the calculator values.

| A (standard) | B (standard) | C (number; 30 decimals; Formula: A/B) | D (number; 30 decimals; Formula: C*B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 897,8 | 1046,15 | 0,858194331596807000000000000000 | 897,800000000000000000000000000000 |

If I set columns C and D to standard, there is magic auto-rounding (how does that work?):

| A (standard) | B (standard) | C (standard; Formula: A/B) | D (standard; Formula: C*B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 897,8 | 1046,15 | 0,858194332 (rounded to 9 decimals) | 897,8 (rounded to 1 decimal) |

Calculator check:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 897,8 | 1046,15 | 0,858194331596807000000000000000 (taken from table 1) | 897,79999999999964305 |
| 897,8 | 1046,15 | 0,858194332 (taken from table 2) | 897,8000004218 |
| 897,8 | 1046,15 | 0,85819433159680734120346030683936 (correct quotient from A/B) | 897,8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the display format and the actual values, excel is working with. Internally excel always works with 15 significant digits, regardless of whether you display only 2 of them or 30.

So let's assume the correct mathematical result is `1.23456789`. You now decide to display only 6 decimal places, then excel will display `1.23457` (ie 6 decimal places, the last one rounded). But it still internally will use the correct value for further calculations. You can easily see this, when you click into the cell, it will display the correct value at the top. See the following image

[image]

If you decide to display let's say 20 digits, excel will fill up the missing places in the display with `0`, but internally of course still work with the original value. See the following image

[image]

But if now the correct mathematical value is something like `1.23456789123456789123456789`, excel doesn't have enough precision to hold the complete value, so it cuts the result to the number of significant digits it can handle. See the following image, where I pasted the above number into excel. Excel now internally cut this number at the defined precision and for display it replaced them with `0`, just because it can't handle them. There is also no rounding of the last `6` because for excel that `7` following the `6` in the original value just doesn't exist, because it's beyond precision. All excel sees and works with is `1.23456789123456`

[image]

Now the "General" or default formatting for a cell is displaying up to a certain amout of digits (10 probably, couldn't find a specification for that), but only if this is necessary. So trailing zeros after the comma are removed, and if your number is longer than that, rounding is applied. See also the following screenshot. All visible cells are set to "General" formatting. The first two rows display the exact values, because the fit into these 10 digits, thus they are display exactly as they are. The last row, has more than 10 decimal places, so the display is cut (and if necessary rounded) after 10 digits, but the original value can still be seen in the input above ...

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to see the internal number if the field above the column shows the formula?

Comment: Format the cell to display at least 15 decimal places...

Comment: What about the term 1/3 * 3 = 1. There is no difference between output and display format. According to your explanation, Excel should actually use 0.9999999999... and display 1. But if I set the number of digits to 15, it says 1.000000000 and even if I calculate with the result and multiply by 1,000,000, it doesn't say 999,999,999... but 1,000,000. So there must be rounding.

Comment: Also that probably has do with binary vs decimal. Not all decimal values that can be expressed in binary can be expressed in decimal and vice versa. Internally excel is of course working with binary numbers and converts them to decimal only for display. Which also leads to certain inaccuracies. Might be the case here

Answer (score 2):

This is Excel specifications and limit [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

According to this

**Calculation specifications and limits**

| Feature | Maximum limit |
| --- | --- |
| Number precision | 15 digits |
| Smallest allowed negative number | -2.2251E-308 |
| Smallest allowed positive number | 2.2251E-308 |
| Largest allowed positive number | 9.99999999999999E+307 |
| Largest allowed negative number | -9.99999999999999E+307 |
| Largest allowed positive number via formula | 1.7976931348623158e+308 |
| Largest allowed negative number via formula | -1.7976931348623158e+308 |

The `General` number format is as is.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any official documentation on how exactly `General` format works in Excel, so just did a quick test myself:

[image]

- a maximum of 10 digits are shown (sum of count of digits before and after decimal separator)
- depending on column width, there could be less number of digits shown to ensure number fits available space
- leading trailing `0`s are not shown

For the specific examples in the question:

- `0.858194332` - maximum of 10 digits are shown (`0` + 9 decimals)
- `897.79999999999964305` - rounding to 10 digits is `897.8000000`, removing trailing `0`s gives you `897.8`, which is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Excel calculates with a guaranteed accuracy of up to 15 significant digits, but in reality it still has a small margin of precision for rounding. But it doesn't normally display these extra digits (unless we plan special calculations).
In the `General` format, a number is written at up to 11 decimal positions (including the decimal point, not including the minus sign) if the cell width allows. But the accuracy of the number in memory is higher, so the calculation results are presented with a full accuracy of 15 digits.
If you write the calculation like this:
`=1000*897,8/1046,15-858`
This is the result you will get:
`0,194331596807274`
That is, 3 additional decimal places (not necessarily exact).
If you now perform the reverse calculation:
`0,194331596807274*1046,15 = 203,29999999993`
`858*1046,15 = 897596,7`
Total (no longer in Excel) `= 897799,99999999993`
You can see that on the 16th decimal place is 9, so this is correctly rounded to 15 places.